# How can I count the number of documents where a field is within a certain range?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build an elasticsearch query that counts the number of documents where a certain field is within a certain range. This aggregation is also contained inside of a date histogram aggregation, but I don't think that matters for the purpose of this question.

Example Data:

```
ID: Score
01: 4
02: 5
03: 10    
04: 9
```

I would like to count the number of documents where 'Score' is >= 9. I have tried scripts and filters within this aggregation, but I can't get it to work.

This aggregation counts all documents, not just the ones that match the script.

```
"aggs": {
    "report_days": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "Date",
            "interval": "day"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "value_count": {
                "field": "Score",
                "script": "_value >=9"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This following aggregation gives me a parse failure, saying `Parse Failure [Expected [START_OBJECT] under [field], but got a [VALUE_STRING] in [value_count]]`:

```
"aggs": {
    "report_days": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "Date",
            "interval": "day"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "value_count": {
                "field": "Score",
                "filter": {
                    "range": {
                        "Score": {
                            "gte": 9
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the number of docs with score >= 9

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "score": {
        "gte": 9
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this agg will do the same

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my agg": {
      "range": {
        "field": "score",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 9
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the query ("score:>9") and check the hits->total value.  See the examples in [the doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html).